# .Net Build Automation

Tags: visual-studio, build

I'm looking for some resources on build automation with VS2005 (VS2008 soon). I'd like to do things like delete all my files in my output folder, move all my build output to one folder, etc. I think this stuff is pretty basic but I don't know where to get started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the Post Build Event in your project (right-click, select Properties). This will allow you to execute anything you could type in the command line, so you can either write it all there or create a small command line utility to take care of it for you.

Comment: So I could write a batch file or even a console app to do some of this stuff for me? I'll check that out. . .

Comment: Or you could write an MSBuild script:-)

Answer (score 7):

If you plan on expanding your build automation in the future. I would suggest looking into msbuild or nant. Both offer a lot more than just clean up operations. VS2008 uses msbuild as the main build engine. I'd also look into continuous integration software such as CruiseControl.net.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at UppercuT. It has a lot of bang for your buck and it does what you are looking for and much more.

UppercuT uses NAnt to build and it is the insanely easy to use Build Framework.

Automated Builds as easy as (1) solution name, (2) source control path, (3) company name for most projects!!!

http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/

Some good explanations here: [UppercuT](http://ferventcoder.com/category/10094.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I'd normally recommend makefiles. But one other option is to install PowerShell, create an script and call it from VS' postbuild.

Comment: I'm sure you could write build scripts in PowerShell... but why would you? MSBuild is the way to go (for .Net solutions as least).